# Insert Multivalue, MYSQL DB Structure

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

The Following Codes are examples I made up to depict my situation.

I have 3 html 'Selects' with multiple options. Each day, users have to select a minimum of one option for each 'Select'.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="frm" action="Save.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" readonly='true'>
<select id="OptionType1" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="OptionType2" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="OptionType3" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
</form>
</body></html>

CREATE TABLE `m` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Client ID` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Category` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'categoryA-1,categoryB-2,categoryC-3',
`OptionsType1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`OptionsType2` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`OptionsType3` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This DB Structure can only take one OptionType value each.

`Client ID`,`Date`,`Category` are used to make a unique index. The unique index is used for "Insert Into... ON Duplicate Key Update". The reason I used the unique index is so the user can go back and edit their option and mysql will update it based on the unique index.

Due to the Unique Index I cannot make multiple rows with the same `Client ID`,`Date`,`Category`. My only other option is to concatenate my values together in the same row but that could cause performance issues if I decided to look for those values down the line.

Can anyone help me with this dilemma. I need the right structure to save my multiple values and be able to load it back on html and have the user able to update it. Thanks

UPDATE:
Two tables are created

```
CREATE TABLE `m` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Client ID` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Category` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'categoryA-1,categoryB-2,categoryC-3',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `uniq` (`Client ID`,`Date`,`Category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `c` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`OptionsType1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`OptionsType2` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`OptionsType3` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`REF ID` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Is there a way to replace existing data (c table) without deleting. Unique index does not exist on c table only primary key but i do not keep track of that when loading html form.

Comment: date column is there, can you rephrase your question i'm not understanding it. Thanks

Comment: I misread. Don't have the `OptionType` columns. Use 2 tables and have `OptionType` and the value in the other table with an id that maps back to the `m` table.

Comment: Separate m table with `ID`,`Client ID`,`Date`,`Category` and c table with `Primarykey ID`,`OptionsType1`,`OptionsType2`,`OptionsType3`,`Reference ID` and join m.`ID`on c.`Reference ID`? Seems like a good idea

Comment: I think that will solve my DB issue. but I think that might cause me headaches with my "Insert Into on duplicate key update"

Comment: You don't need the `insert`/`update` query at that point. If it is an insert that conflicts it is an error no because they should't be able to update multiple times? If I misread though than issue the constraint and update on the second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to concatenate, you can create a new table just for the values and referencing the `m` table.

For the `m` table you can replace the OptionsType[1-3] fields by one column wherein the number of the OptionsType is persisted and adding this new column to the shared unique key.

In the values table, you reference the id of the `m` table and place therein the option number and the user selection.

---

*To elaborate on the solution, after a referencing table got accepted and the question was adjusted:*

First I show the table creation, afterwards I explain it.

**Table m**

`` CREATE TABLE `m` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Client ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `Category` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'categoryA-1,categoryB-2,categoryC-3',
    `OptionsType` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Client ID_Date_Category_OptionsType` (`Client ID`, `Date`, `Category`, `OptionsType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; ``

**Table c**

`` CREATE TABLE `c` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `mID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Option` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Value` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `mID_Option` (`mID`, `Option`),
    INDEX `mID` (`mID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; ``

**Explanation**

Add `OptionsType` to table `m`. In table `c` you reference table `m` via `m.ID=c.mID`. To ensure no duplicates are being persisted, a unique index is set over `mID` and `Option`.The `Option` column shows which option is referred to and `value` shows the selection of the user. With this schema you're also not limited to three options per select.

**Example query**

`` SELECT * FROM `m` INNER JOIN `c` ON `m`.`ID`=`c`.`mID`;
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-------------+----+-----+--------+-------+
| ID | Client ID | Date       | Category | OptionsType | ID | mID | Option | Value |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-------------+----+-----+--------+-------+
|  1 |      4711 | 2018-06-27 |        1 |           1 |  1 |   1 |      1 |     0 |
|  1 |      4711 | 2018-06-27 |        1 |           1 |  2 |   1 |      2 |     1 |
|  1 |      4711 | 2018-06-27 |        1 |           1 |  3 |   1 |      3 |     0 |
|  3 |      4711 | 2018-06-27 |        1 |           2 |  7 |   3 |      1 |     0 |
|  3 |      4711 | 2018-06-27 |        1 |           2 |  8 |   3 |      2 |     1 |
|  3 |      4711 | 2018-06-27 |        1 |           2 |  9 |   3 |      3 |     0 |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-------------+----+-----+--------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec) ``

Comment: Thanks user3783243 also mentioned that which sounds about the right structure for my DB but it might cause issues with my insert update query

Comment: I edited my answer to go a bit more into detail. This should make the schema question clear.
As for the insert and update queries, you probably want to check first if an entry already exists. But this is another question.

Comment: Thanks for your update, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this. Can you explain what the option column is for? If option column has "1" that cannot be used to determine that the first option was selected because the order of options can change. Value column is used to save the option's value and ill use that to load the saved data back to the form. So is it necessary to have UNIQUE INDEX `mID_Option` when i can have multiple values linking to UNIQUE INDEX `Client ID_Date_Category_OptionsType`

Comment: I believe I have figured out insert, update and delete data. I will post my method once i complete it. i will mostly use the schema you provided thanks

Comment: I see the confusion. As I look at it now, the naming can be improved. To explain: `option` is meant for the HTML option value and `value` for whether the user has selected the option or not.

Comment: I decided to use Option column to keep track of the amount of saved "options" and value to enter the value of the option. Only selected options will POST so your method wouldn't work as i wouldn't keep track of options that are not selected. I will post my solution once I finish completing it. Hopefully it can help others.